# Knime: If Contains Statement

Tags: if-statement, knime

I’m trying to familiarize myself with column expressions node but having difficulties, can someone help me write out an “if contains” statement?

I’d like to say:

if column(A) contains category or value or data
then column (B)
 else

I know that I can do the same thing in rule engine and I was able to accomplish this statement in that node but I really want to understand column expressions node and how to write statements in it.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In [Column Expressions](https://kni.me/n/2_0ji_xeG-SudFu-) node syntax and grammar of the expressions are based on the JavaScript Language. That being said here is if/else syntax:

```
if (condition) {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Depending what is behind your "contains" you might want to use regex functions available in this node.

For writing JavaScript in Column Expressions node I consult [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) web page.